# Use of the word en

Tags: en

I live in a French-speaking part of the world and still can't wrap my head around "en" as a particle. I came across this sentence today:

> un monde sans danseurs n'en est pas un

I usually understand "en" to be used to translate to something like "about it" ex. :

> - Je m'en fous
> - Je n'en sais rien (de ça)

How is the "en" being used in the sentence about a world without dancers? I don't see how it changes the meaning of "A world without dancers isn't one."

Help!

Comment: It's because you can't say: un monde sans danseurs n'est pas un which**would mean** A world without dancers is not one [the number]. To say: A world without dancers is not a world, the en has to replace world. I don't know if you can *hear that* or not, but that's the reason.  The verb foutre takes de. Je me fous de cette histoire. Je m'en fous. I don't give a fuck **about** that story or thing.

Comment: Pronouns are not always about meaning.

Answer (score 3):

There are two versions of *en*. (It sounds like you know the following, but just to be clear...)

One is a preposition. This usually means "in" or "while" (but can mean several other things).

The other is a pronoun. This replaces "de ____", so it could be translated "of it", "of them".

> Il reste quelques biscuits. J'en ai mangé trois. (I ate three of them)

If you were to leave off the number, we'd get English "I ate some (of them)".

> As-tu essayé les biscuits ? Paul en a mangé (he ate some of them), et il dit qu'ils sont bons.

Now for your world sentence. Suppose we drop *en*: you'd still have *un* "one", but you'd have to ask: one *what*?

This is what *en* does as a pronoun. It gives us the implicit *un (des mondes)*. "One what? One world."

Ben points out in the comment that you could also repeat the main noun itself:

> Un monde sans danseurs n'est pas un monde.

Also, I didn't think about this before, but you could leave out *en* and have it just mean "A world without dansers isn't *one*" -- isn't unified and whole. But that's not what you mean, of course :)

Comment: Just to write down the full sentence in french : "un monde sans danceurs n'en est pas un" : "en" is a pronoun as explained above. You could also say it without pronoun : "un monde sans danceurs n'est pas un monde".

Comment: Yes, you have to say en or you get un meaning unfied or whole, precisely. With foutre, it's because on se fou **de** quelque chose.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your sentence, made more explicit :

> Un monde sans danseurs n'est pas un monde.

Let's avoid repetition by using *en* :

> un monde sans danseurs n'en est pas un. [de monde]

Though less common with *être*, the logic is similar to the classic construction with *avoir* :

> Combien ai-je de frères ? J'ai un frère.

Let's avoid the repetition by using *en* :

> Combien ai-je de frères ? J'en ai un. [de frère]